# Which type of random walk has distribution of "scaled" binomial coefficient?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-theorem

We know that, for a 1D symmetrical random walk, ${\displaystyle p = 1/2, q = 1/2}$, with equal walk step length, after n steps, its probability distribution will be proportional to binomial coefficient:

${\displaystyle f(k) = {n \choose k}}$

or in the continuous limit, its probability distribution will be Gaussian-normal distribution.

My question is, which type of random walk can have "scaled" binominal coefficient  distribution ? that is, its distribution is:

${\displaystyle g(k) = f(ak), a > 0}$

I tried different walk step length for "walk to the left" and "walk to the right",  (asymmetrical random walk), I could not get above distribution.

Can anyone help ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you mean $g(k)=\large{{\binom{n}{a\cdot  k}}}$?

Comment: That is what I mean

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the random walk probabilities are proportional to $$\binom{n}{(n+k)/2},$$
not $\binom{n}k$. The walk is symmetric, so the formula needs to be symmetric when the sign of $k$ changes.

If you want to scale the distribution, just scale the step size. The simple random walk whose step sizes are $\pm 1/a$ will have distribution proportional to
$$
\binom{n}{(n+xa)/2}
$$
where $x$ is the position you are trying to find the probability of.

Comment: Thank you for the post.

Comment: Thank you for the post.  Maybe my question is not clear. Here is what I am looking for. For example, original symmetric random walk, after walk 100 steps, the possible end positions can be  [0, 1, 2, ...., 100] with probability f(k) where k = 0, 1, 2, ..., 100. I am looking for another random walk, after 100 steps, the possible end position can be [0, 1, ..., 10] with distribution g(k) = f(10k). What kind of random walk can satisfy above requirements ?  Maybe I shall not call this "scaled" binomial coefficient, maybe i shall call it "squeezed" binomial coefficient.

Comment: I now understand your question and have no idea how to answer it.